# How do I generate a return URL in an action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I created my own login logic for a set of web applications. A future version of this project will have a portal-like interface which would then utilize the ASP.NET MVC login logic.

One thing I am trying to figure out is how to build a return URL dynamically based on what controller/action I am in. I am currently doing:

```
public ActionResult Action(LogggedInCustomer logIn, string id)
{
    if (logIn == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", 
            new { returnUrl = "/AR/Invoice/Print/" + id });
}
```

The application will reside in a folder on the server (domain.com/app). I want to build the return UL more dynamically (if possible). How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url.aspx) property:

```
public ActionResult Action(LogggedInCustomer logIn, string id)
{
    if (logIn == null)
    {
        var returnUrl = Url.Action("Print", "Invoice", new { area = "AR", id = id });
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not hard-code the action and route? Pick it up from the action I am in?

Comment: @MikeWills, sure, just put `null`.